# Posting Files to API

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I am posting an image to my API using `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "6.3"`. When I post image to my API, I get `false` when I check for the file using `hasFile().` Could it be that the file is not being submitted to my API?

**Controller**

```php
$client = new Client();
$url = 'http://localhost:9000/api';
$path = 'app/public/images/';
$name = '94.jpeg';
$myBody['fileinfo'] = ['449232323023'];
$myBody['image'] = file_get_contents($path.$name);
$request = $client->post($url, ['form_params' => $myBody]);
$response = $request->getBody();

return $response;
```

**API**

```php
if (!$request->hasFile('image')) {
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'No file',
        'photo' => $request->hasFile('image'),
        'photo_size' => $request->file('image')->getSize()
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add your `form_params` to the `multipart` array:

```
// untested code

$client = new Client();

$endpoint = 'http://localhost:9000/api';
$filename = '94.jpeg';
$image = public_path('images/' . $filename);

$request = $client->post($endpoint, [
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name' => 'fileinfo',
            'contents' => '449232323023',
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'file',
            'contents' => fopen($image, 'r'),
        ],
    ],
]);

$response = $request->getBody();

return $response;
```